# Can I set properties to the MessageContext before invoke the stub in Axis 2 Java

Tags: java, web-services, wso2, apache-axis, webservice-client

I'm using AXIS 2 to call WS methods using a stub called ChannelConnectServiceStub.

**Generating stub and the ConfigurationContext :**

```
public class TestWSClient {

    private void init() throws Exception {

        String                  proxyUrl                    = "http://subdom.dom.com/testpath/TestConnect.asmx";
        ConfigurationContext    ctx                         = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem("/rootFolder/Axis2/axis2-1.4.1/repository", "/rootFolder/Axis2/axis2-1.4.1/conf/axis2.xml");
        ChannelConnectServiceStub channelConnectServiceStub = new ChannelConnectServiceStub(ctx,proxyUrl);

        ctx.setProperty("testid", "testidval"); // Approach 1
        channelConnectServiceStub._getServiceClient().getServiceContext().setProperty("testid", "testidval"); // Approach 2

    }
}
```

And I'm using a LogHandler to log the Message requests and responses.

**LogHandler :**

```
class LogHandler extends AbstractHandler implements Handler {

    @Override
    public InvocationResponse invoke(MessageContext messageContext) throws AxisFault {

        String testID       = null;
        String invokeStr    = null;
        String axisService  = null;
        String action       = null;

        invokeStr       = messageContext.getEnvelope().toString();
        axisService     = messageContext.getAxisService().getName();
        action          = messageContext.getAxisMessage().getAxisOperation().getInputAction();

        testID = (String) messageContext.getProperty("testid");// Approach 1
        testID = (String) messageContext.getServiceContext().getProperty("testid");// Approach 2

        return InvocationResponse.CONTINUE;
    }

}
```

I want to pass a property ("testid") from the point that I creating and calling the stub to the LogHandler class. I have mentioned two approaches that I've taken.

Both are passing the value. But the problem is, there are multiple client threads using the same TestWSClient to use the service. So, different values that are setting by different clients are getting interchange when it came to the LogHandler. (But invokeStr, AxisService and action don't have this issue).

1. Is there any way to pass properties to the MessageContext before the
   stub is invoked?
2. Can anybody help to get a property from stub to the
   LogHandler without interchanging the values in multi-threaded
   environment.

I tried below one also but failed since `operationContext` is NULL.

```
OperationContext operationContext = stub._getServiceClient().getLastOperationContext();
logger.info("operationContext : " + operationContext);

if (operationContext != null) {

    MessageContext outMessageContext = operationContext.getMessageContext("Out");

    if (outMessageContext != null) {
        logger.info("outMessageContext.getEnvelope().toString() : " + outMessageContext.getEnvelope().toString());
        outMessageContext.setProperty("Portal", getPortal());
    }

    MessageContext inMessageContext = operationContext.getMessageContext("In");
    logger.info("inMessageContext : " + inMessageContext);

    if (inMessageContext != null) {
        logger.info("inMessageContext.getEnvelope().toString() : " + inMessageContext.getEnvelope().toString());
        inMessageContext.setProperty("Portal", getPortal());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to get singleton instance of ConfigurationContext.

when you do setProperty and getProperty from ServiceContext note that you are obtaining a shared copy of Property object per jvm, so instead of "testid" key, use a unique key,

ex:
In client side code after stub initialization instead of,

```
channelConnectServiceStub._getServiceClient().getServiceContext()
  .setProperty("testid","testidval");
```

try

```
channelConnectServiceStub._getServiceClient().getServiceContext()
 .setProperty(stub._getServiceClient().getServiceContext().getName(), "testidval");
```

and to retrieve the property, in loghandler use the same key (the `msgContext.getServiceContext().getName()` is unique per flow)

Instead of

`messageContext.getServiceContext().getProperty("testid");`

try

```
messageContext.getServiceContext()
 .getProperty(msgContext.getServiceContext().getName());
```

also note as you are storing values on a jvm shared Property object, to avoid memory growth remove the value once its no longer needed.

```
messageContext.getServiceContext()
 .removeProperty(msgContext.getServiceContext().getName();
```

Answer (score 1):

To set different properties for different messages you need to set them in the Messagecontext. But at the client stub message context will be null. Setting the property at Servicecontext is like; that property is alive till service invocation finishes.

What you can do is, from the client stub, add a custom soap header and set ID  in the header..Read that Header from the handler.

```
ServiceClient serviceClient = stub._getServiceClient();
serviceClient.addStringHeader("xx")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I got the Custom header at the Request. But the service doesn't provide a header in the response. Then how can I read it in the response?

Comment: Actually if you set the header at request, you should be able to read the header at the handler, if that handler is placed in IN Flow. If your service is not responding with the header, then you can not get the detail at your handler, if that handler kept in the OUTFlow. ..So, you need to make sure to set the header from the service

Comment: Many thanks. But I don't have a control to the Service dear. I'm using only the  client. So, that means in the OUT Flow i don't have those information right?

Comment: yes..if your response doesn't have any related headers set,then you cannot get at outflow..but if you want to set any custom header at outflow for your response, which may need for your client..you can set at handler level.